# Share NHibernate parameter in multiple queries

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have two queries, first query return top 10/20 recoords, second query return  total record count from first query. Both queries need to use same filter condition.

How can I write filter condition and parameter used in filter condition in one place and use in both the queries.

Condition I can store in string variable and use in both the queries but how to share parameters?

I am using HQL

Answer (score 1):

Check this similar Q & A: [Nhibernate migrate ICriteria to QueryOver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40446487/1679310)

There is a native support in NHiberante for row count. Let's have some query

```
// the QueryOver
var query = session.QueryOver<MyEntity>();
```

It could have any amount of where parts, projections... Now we just take its underlying criteria and use a transformer to create brand new criteria - out-of-box ready to get total rowcount

```
// GET A ROW COUNT query (ICriteria)
var rowCount = CriteriaTransformer.TransformToRowCount(query.UnderlyingCriteria);
```

Next step is to use FUTURE to get both queries in one round trip to DB

```
// ask for a list, but with a Future, to combine both in one SQL statement
var list = query
    .Future<MyEntity>()
    .ToList();

// execute the main and count query at once
var count = rowCount
    .FutureValue<int>()
    .Value;

// list is now in memory, ready to be used
var list = futureList
    .ToList();
```